# How to set absolute position for each item in IText Fabricjs

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

Please help me, how to set absolute position of each text item in IText Fabricjs. In this example, I want text "KÍNH MỜI" is align horizontal center with below text. 

Expected Result: 
[image: Expected Result]

Actual Result: 
[image: Actual Result]

Here is my code:

```js
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("editorCanvas");
// set canvas equal size with div
$(canvasObject).width($("#canvasContainer").width());
$(canvasObject).height($("#canvasContainer").height());

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editorCanvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  selectionLineWidth: 2,
  width: $("#canvasContainer").width(),
  height: $("#canvasContainer").height()
});

var textbox1 = new fabric.IText("KÍNH MỜI\n \n.......................................................................................", {
  left: 162, 
  top: 50, 
  width: 216.125889, 
  fontSize: 11.3735, 
  fontFamily: 'Times New Roman', 
  fontWeight: 'normal', 
  fill: "#404041",
  editable: false, 
  styles: { 
    0: {
      0: { fontFamily: 'Times New Roman', fontSize: '11.3735', fill: '#404041' }
    },
    1: {
      0: { fontFamily: 'Times New Roman', fontSize: '11.3735', fill: '#404041' }
    },
    2: {
      0: { fontFamily: 'Times New Roman', fontSize: '7.4898', fill: '#404041' }
    }
  }
});
canvas.add(textbox1); 
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
#canvasContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
  
<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="editorCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`textAlign: center`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#textAlign). I also changed `lineHeight` to 1 (default is 1.16) to make it look more like your expected result.

```js
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("editorCanvas");
// set canvas equal size with div
$(canvasObject).width($("#canvasContainer").width());
$(canvasObject).height($("#canvasContainer").height());

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editorCanvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  selectionLineWidth: 2,
  width: $("#canvasContainer").width(),
  height: $("#canvasContainer").height()
});

var textbox1 = new fabric.IText("KÍNH MỜI\n \n.......................................................................................", {
  left: 162, 
  top: 50, 
  width: 216.125889, 
  fontSize: 11.3735, 
  fontFamily: 'Times New Roman', 
  fontWeight: 'normal', 
  textAlign: 'center',
  lineHeight: 1,
  fill: "#404041",
  editable: false, 
  styles: { 
    0: {
      0: { fontFamily: 'Times New Roman', fontSize: '11.3735', fill: '#404041' }
    },
    1: {
      0: { fontFamily: 'Times New Roman', fontSize: '11.3735', fill: '#404041' }
    },
    2: {
      0: { fontFamily: 'Times New Roman', fontSize: '7.4898', fill: '#404041' }
    }
  }
});
canvas.add(textbox1); 
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
#canvasContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
  
<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="editorCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer shkaper. By the way, is there any way to style array of characters instead of style one by one character with fabric.IText ?

Comment: No, not that I know of

Comment: @ThoBuiNgoc [setSelectionStyles](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html#setSelectionStyles)

Comment: Thank Durga, That's a great solution! Let me try it !